# System.LimitException: Too many DML statements

Tags: apex, class

I want to mass update my account record. But I got this error when trying to deploy the code.

```
public class Insert_CustID_Old {

    public void insertCustId() {
        List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Cust_ID_SUJ__c, Cust_ID_SUJ_EBS_Old__c FROM Account WHERE Cust_ID_SUJ__c != NULL];
        for(Account acc : accList){
            Account accNew = new Account();
            accNew.Id = acc.id;
            accNew.Cust_ID_SUJ_EBS_Old__c = acc.Cust_ID_SUJ__c;
            Update accNew;
        }
    }
}
```

> System.LimitException: Too many DML statements: 151

Comment: Maintain  a Accuount list and update outside the for loop and learn about the apex governer limits https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

Comment: You need to review some Apex Trailhead modules like [Understand Execution Context](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_basics_dotnet/units/execution_context)

Comment: is it resolved?

Comment: sorry @RatanPaul it takes forever for me to reply.. yes it is.. thanks a lot..!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a single transaction, we have a limit of 150 DML

so if your SOQL query returns 151 records then for loop iterate over 151 time and Update accNew; will execute 151 times means you are doing 151 time DML operation that's why this error occurred.

To resolve this issue put this record into a list and update the list ex.

```
List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Cust_ID_SUJ__c, Cust_ID_SUJ_EBS_Old__c FROM Account WHERE Cust_ID_SUJ__c != NULL];

List<Account> accListToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    for (Account acc : accList){
        Account accNew = new Account();
        accNew.Id = acc.id;
        accNew.Cust_ID_SUJ_EBS_Old__c = acc.Cust_ID_SUJ__c;
        accListToUpdate.add(accNew);
    }
update accListToUpdate; //perform update outside the loop so only single dml required.
```

### Another way

Since you are updating the list then you could do like this.

```
List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Cust_ID_SUJ__c, Cust_ID_SUJ_EBS_Old__c FROM Account WHERE Cust_ID_SUJ__c != NULL];

    for (Account acc : accList){
        //this will update the list only. 
        acc.Cust_ID_SUJ_EBS_Old__c = acc.Cust_ID_SUJ__c;
    }
update accList ; //perform update outside the loop so only single dml required.
```

Answer (score 3):

Use DML statement (`update`) outside of `for` loop.

Secondly, you dont need to create separate account instance for updating. You should update the `list` which has been retrieved via SOQL query.

```
public class Insert_CustID_Old {

    public void insertCustId() {
        List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Cust_ID_SUJ__c, Cust_ID_SUJ_EBS_Old__c FROM Account WHERE Cust_ID_SUJ__c != NULL];
        for (Account acc : accList){
            accNew.Cust_ID_SUJ_EBS_Old__c = acc.Cust_ID_SUJ__c;         
        }
        update accList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use dml opertation in for loop it is not best practice. use below code you can avoid this error.

```
 public class Insert_CustID_Old {

public void insertCustId() {
List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Cust_ID_SUJ__c, Cust_ID_SUJ_EBS_Old__c FROM Account WHERE Cust_ID_SUJ__c != NULL];
List<Account> updateList = new updateList();
for (Account acc : accList){
    Account accNew = new Account();
    accNew.Id = acc.id;
    accNew.Cust_ID_SUJ_EBS_Old__c = acc.Cust_ID_SUJ__c;
    updateList.add(accNew);
  }
   if(updateList.size()>0 && updateList !=null){
       update updateList;

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to insert more than 1 record, you need to add records into a list and then perform a bulk DML. This will help you to avoid governor limits.

> You can Update your code as below. Declare a list and inside for loop you can add records to that list and then make a dml call outside for loop.

```
public class Insert_CustID_Old {

 public void insertCustId() {

 //create a list to update account records in bulk
 List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>(); 

 List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Cust_ID_SUJ__c, Cust_ID_SUJ_EBS_Old__c 
 FROM Account WHERE Cust_ID_SUJ__c != NULL];
 for (Account acc : accList){
     Account accNew = new Account();
     accNew.Id = acc.id;
     accNew.Cust_ID_SUJ_EBS_Old__c = acc.Cust_ID_SUJ__c;
     accountsToUpdate.add(accNew); // add the record to the list 
   }
  Update accountsToUpdate; //perform a bulk DML
 }
```

**Refer this links to get more Idea:**

[Manipulate records with bulk DML](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_database/units/apex_database_dml)

[Solving Too Many DML Statements Error](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092MtIAI)